# Json schema. How to validate property keys based of another property value?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Data:

```
{
   "languages": ['en', 'ch'],
   "file": {
      "en": "file1",
      "ch": "file2"
    }
}
```

How to define a schema that verifies name of keys in file property by "languages" property?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "file": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": ????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define additional data constrains using custom keywords, that are supported by some validators, e.g. [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) (I am the author):

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv;
ajv.addKeyword('validateLocales', {
    type: 'object',
    compile: function(schema) {
        return function(data, dataPath, parentData) {
            for (var prop in data) {
                if (parentData[schema.localesProperty].indexOf(prop) == -1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    },
    metaSchema: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            localesProperty: { type: 'string' }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
    }
});

var schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "file": {
      "type": "object",
      "validateLocales": {
          "localesProperty": "languages"
      },
      "additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }
    }
  }
};

var data = {
   "languages": ['en', 'ch'],
   "file": {
      "en": "file1",
      "ch": "file2"
    }
};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
console.log(validate(data));
```

See https://runkit.com/esp/57d9d419646b97130082de34

Comment: What if i need to put my file 2 or more levels deep? e.g.
https://gist.github.com/Truedrog/201c34a1f9b119d1416eeff485b8c3cc

Comment: also in compilation function schema.localesProperty equales 'languages', not they key of my languages array so `parentData[schema.localesProperty].indexOf(prop) == -1` couldn't check because of the undefined error.

Comment: Well, i workarounded my problem with the root data argument.
Could it be done with $data reference from v5 proposal?

Comment: Custom keywords in Ajv have some support for $data reference

Comment: I meant can i use only $data reference without custom keyword to achieve such validation with following schema:
https://gist.github.com/Truedrog/201c34a1f9b119d1416eeff485b8c3cc?

Comment: Tried this thing 
`"validateLocales": {
          "$data": "0#"
      },
`
and it didn't work. Maybe i should read more docs, but i didn't find any usage of $data ref in custom keywords.

Comment: $data reference is a reference to a point in data. So this: `"validateLocales": { "$data": "0#" }` would mean that you expect the schema for validateLocales is a property name of the current property... Not sure how you expect it to work. You can achieve that the property name for locales is stored in some other property, not sure why it is needed though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `"validateLocales": { "$data": "0#" }` would be no use in this case. Didn't say it was only for tes purpose. I meant when i've tried to do this like here https://runkit.com/truedrog/57e4eedff5dd4c1400890890

Comment: The output was not the same as it was expected to see - '0#'.

My actually goal is to let nested "file object" has ' ' for default, and strict it for values of language array. E.g. user can put in ch or en or ' ', but not uk.

Comment: You can do it with a custom keyword, no idea how to do it with $data

Comment: Ok. Got it. But should i rely on root data which passed to compilation function in my case (deep nested property)?

Comment: Could you please let me know how to work with nesting? validating an array item for example because the parent data is always the array itself and not the whole data object.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely not possible to express such constraint with json schema.